# How to visualize graph in PyQt GUI program?

Tags: python, pyqt5, networkx

I am working on a community detection GUI program in PyQt5. In a section of my program I want to visualize a network (Graph) which I have found its communities.
When i run the program in non-GUI way everything is OK and the graph is visualized in the browser but when i put the code in GUI again everything runs correctly and the program ends with no errors, but the graph is not shown in the browser.
I appreciate any help on this problem.
The code below shows how i  visualize the graph. `coms.communities` is the communities which i have found using CDLIB library and `nodes_list` holds the label of each node. I aimed to color the nodes in same community with same color and because of that i use the labeles of nodes to give them same color.

```
            palette = (sns.color_palette("Pastel1", n_colors=len(coms.communities))) 
            palette = palette.as_hex()
            colorDict = {}
            counter = 0
            for i in palette:
                colorDict[counter] = i
                counter += 1
            N = Network(height='100%', width='100%', directed=False, notebook=False)
            for n in G.nodes:
                N.add_node(n, color=(colorDict[nodes_list[n]]), size=5)

            for e in G.edges.data():
                N.add_edge(e[0], e[1])
            N.show('result.html')
```

Everything is OK with code but i don't know how to use this code in a GUI program to show the constructed graph in a browser.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the code shows everything is OK and i tested your code and it works correctly. Make sure that you have not put any other code such as `return ...`  before this code because it ends the program at that line and does not allow the program to continue your visualization code

Comment: thank you very much for your answer. yes i have mistakenly put an ```return``` before visualization!! You solved my problem thank you